# How to bypass "Always on VPN" demand for numeric IP and use a domain instead?

Tags: vpn

I know that it is not required but still I want to use a domain name for VPN server address and be able to tick to "Always On VPN" on Android.

I am open to any Idea with advantage to idea that can be use also on unrooted machine?

The reason is that I want to connect to my home network that has a PPTP VPN server (on Asus router). I dont have fixed IP at home (its very expensive in my country), so I am using Asus dynamic DNS service configured on my router. I want my Android phone to be connected to the internet only via this VPN.

I don't mind using a 3rd party vpn client app (that has "Always on VPN" mode) as long as I can connect to MY own VPN server, not to another party server. Also, if there is a web browser that can be configured to browse the web only via custom VPN settings, it will also be good.

Any Idea will be appreciated!

Comment: You can use any third party VPN app that supports PPTP and domain name, and then enable "Always-on VPN" for that app in Settings.

Comment: I didnt find any 3rd party app that let you enter your own vpn server derails. Can you name one?

Comment: I'm not sure about PPTP because it's not that much secure and getting obsolete (don't know why it's integrated in Android). But there are Android clients for other protocols like OpenVPN, SSTP etc. Personally I run an OpenVPN server with DDNS and I use VPN Client app by colucci-web, combined with shapeshifter (obfs4) commandline tool.